# turbine.cluster-name-expression invalid

Tags: turbine

when i set this in properties

```
turbine.cluster-name-expression="default"
```

i think Hystrix Dashboard monitor turbine seems like be this

book picture:

[image]

this name is application.name and point and server name but in my program it dose't work

like this

my program:

[image]

just have server name without application name and hosts is 2

my to consumer's application name is ribbon-consumer and ribbon-consumer-2 but dose not show

my turbine application.properties is

```
spring.application.name=turbine

server.port=8989
management.port=8990

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:1111/eureka/

turbine.app-config=RIBBON-CONSUMER,RIBBON-CONSUMER-2
turbine.cluster-name-expression="default"
turbine.combine-host-port=true
```

i'm chinese my english so poor sorry